# VB.Net List all Users From MySQL and assign them to a variable

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have code here that queries the database to give me the list of users according to the full name. The problem is when I assign the list to a variable then later on I will assign that variable to a listbox it only showed one result. Can anyone please help me?

```
 Private ListofAllUsers As String

 Private Sub GetALLUserList()
        Dim UFullNameList As String

        If DataConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

            Try

                QueryConnect = "SELECT * From users"
                CommandConnect = New MySqlCommand(QueryConnect, DataConnection)

                MyDataConnect = CommandConnect.ExecuteReader
                While MyDataConnect.Read()
                    UFullNameList = MyDataConnect.GetString("FullName")

                    ListofAllUsers = (UFullNameList)

                End While

                MyDataConnect.Close()

            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message, CType(MessageBoxIcon.Error, MsgBoxStyle), LoginUI.BrandMsgBox)
                DataConnection.Close()
            End Try

        Else

            Call GetSoftwareData()

            'Retry Again
            GetALLUserList()

        End If
```

Now then I do this it only showed one can anyone please help me?

```
   UListBox.Items.Add(ListofAllUsers)
```

Comment: Don't you think that something named `ListofAllUsers` should actually be a list of some sort?  Do you understand the difference between combining things and replacing them?  Which one does this do: `ListofAllUsers = (UFullNameList)`?  Here's a hint: there's no combining going on there.

Comment: @jmcilhinney owh thanks for pointing that out ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declares `ListofAllUsers` as a `List (Of String)`

In the while loop, simply add the items to the list of string.

I also added `using` blocks to properly dispose the connections.

```
Private ListofAllUsers As New List (Of String)
Private Sub GetALLUserList()
        Dim UFullNameList As String
        Dim QueryConnect = "SELECT * From users"
        'Add using block to properly dispose stuff.'
        Using DataConnection As New SqlConnection("your connection string"),
              cmd As New SqlCommand(QueryConnect, DataConnection)
            DataConnection.Open()
            Try
                Dim MyDataConnect As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While MyDataConnect.Read()
                    UFullNameList = MyDataConnect.GetString("FullName")
                    'Add the item to the list of string here'
                    ListofAllUsers.Add(UFullNameList)
                End While
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message, CType(MessageBoxIcon.Error, MsgBoxStyle), LoginUI.BrandMsgBox)
            End Try
            DataConnection .Close()
        End Using
End Sub
```

Then you can add the items to the listbox like this:

```
UListBox.Items.AddRange(ListofAllUsers)
```